# Git server with git daemon seem to not care about --base-path

Tags: git, server, repository, clone

I have set git daemon on my server to have my personal git repo following the official documentation. Altho it seems that the `--base-path` does not work as intended, or as specified in the description.

I want to be able to clone a repo as: `git clone git@myserver.com:path/to/repo.git` without having to specify `git clone git@myserver.com:/where/git/user/home/is/path/to/repo.git`

My git daemon service is as follow:

```
/usr/bin/git daemon --export-all --reuseaddr --base-path=/home/git/data/ /home/git/data/
```

Then I created a base repo in `/home/git/data/gns/` (`gns` is like a 'group' where I will have few repos):

`git init --bare gns/api.git`

Locally when I try to clone it I have an error:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ git clone git@myserver.com:gns/api.git     
Cloning into 'api'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
fatal: 'gns/api.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But where it's interesting is that this one works (?!):

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ git clone git@myserver.com:data/gns/api.git
Cloning into 'api'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Any idea what is going on? Why with data/ it works? And what do I miss to make it correctly?

thanks

Comment: It seems to be related to the depth of the path. Using `/home/git` (2 levels) seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know of the [Git daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon), this is for serving repositories using the “Git” protocol.

Meaning URLs starting with `git://...`

But you are not using such URLs, you are using SSH URLs, connecting to `myserver.com` with the remote user `git`, in which home (`/home/git`) there is a `data/gns/api.git` folder.

That would mean the daemon would not be used with such URLs.

Comment: Indeed, I was confused, this daemon listen on 9418 by default. I thought it would be on ssh, thanks for the help.